# Fundamental Theorem of Calculus with limits

Tags: calculus

Find $$\lim_{x\to\infty}(e^{-x^2})\int_{0}^x e^{t^2}dt$$

Isn't this just $1$ because after apply Fundamental Theorem of Calculus you get 
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}(e^{-x^2})e^{x^2}=\lim_{x\to\infty}e^0 =\lim_{x\to\infty}(1)=1$$

But the answer says it's $0$, because $\lim x→∞$  $(e^{-x^2})=0.$ So I'm confused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You replaced $\int_0^x e^{t^2}dt$ with $e^{x^2}$ by saying that it follows from the Fundamental theorem of Calculus, this is not true. At all. Not even a little bit.

A hint for solving your expression:

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}(e^{-x^2})\int_{0}^x e^{t^2}dt = \lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\int_{0}^x e^{t^2}dt}{e^{x^2}}.$$

Comment: It's the differential in terms of x of that expression then right?

Comment: The sentence you just wrote makes no sense to me, sorry. Anyway, take a look at this example:

$$\int_0^x 2t dt = x^2$$

if you would have it your way, then $\int_0^x 2t dt = 2x$, which is not true.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Rewrite the expression and use L'H$\hat{\mathrm{o}}$pitals rule.

Note that, by the fundamental theorem of calculus, the derivative of $$\int_0^x e^{t^2}dt$$ is $$e^{x^2}$$

Comment: @5xum Thanks, yes that was close to what I meant. There was another typo too.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: The FTC says that

\begin{equation}
\left( \int_{a(x)}^{b(x)} f(t)\ dt\right)' = f(b(x))\cdot b'(x)-f(a(x))\cdot a'(x).
\end{equation}